# MySQL get rows as columns

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a the following query

```
SELECT Date(snapshot_date)
     , sku
     , detailed_disposition
     , sum(quantity) 
  FROM clabDevelopment.FBAInventory_fba_history
 group 
    by Date(snapshot_date)
     , sku
     , detailed_disposition;
```

it produces these results [image]

Is it possible to be able to keep the SKU's on one row, and display the quantities as columns

```
   Date      | SKU     |  SELL_QTY |  CUS_DMG_QTY  |  WRE_DMG_QTY  |
2018-03-14     t-bnr       504          2                1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use conditional aggregation over your current result

```
SELECT date, sku
       SUM(case when detailed_disposition = 'sellable'  then Total else 0 end) as sellable,
       SUM(case when detailed_disposition = 'defective' then Total else 0 end) as damage,
       SUM(case when detailed_disposition = 'warehouse' then Total else 0 end) as warehouse
FROM ( 
    SELECT Date(snapshot_date) as date
         , sku
         , detailed_disposition
         , sum(quantity)  as Total
      FROM clabDevelopment.FBAInventory_fba_history
     group 
        by Date(snapshot_date)
         , sku
         , detailed_disposition
     ) as T
GROUP BY date, sku
```